# How to unittest a function that writes xml?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing

I want to unittest a function that outputs data in XML format. A direct string comparison would not work obviously, because the order of the elements and the amount of whitespace do not matter.

Comment: Then you would have to test that the XML parses to the correct values.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What, specifically, do you want to test?  That data was written?  That correct values are genrated?  Both?  Is the XML generated and/or written using another tool or is it all done by hand by you?  There is nowhere near enough information to answer this question.

Comment: The main objective is to test whether whether the output has the correct tree structure. There seems to be the package `XML-unittest`. Has anyone experience with it?

Comment: It looks like [`assertXMLEquivalentOutputs`](http://python-xmlunittest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/xmlunittest.html#xmlunittest.XmlTestMixin.assertXmlEquivalentOutputs) does exactly what you want. You might also want to look at the [source code](https://github.com/Exirel/python-xmlunittest/blob/master/xmlunittest.py#L216); it mentions using lxml's [LXMLOutputChecker](http://lxml.de/3.3/api/lxml.doctestcompare.LXMLOutputChecker-class.html).

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/321795/190597; @ThS: If you test XML-unittest and find it solves your problem, you might want to add it as an answer there.

Comment: @unutbu: I found that `lxml` and `xpath` provide exactly the functionality that compares elements of the XML tree, which I want to do (Also, I now realize how ambigiously and the original post was worded. Can I downvote my own post? ;)